# Where is Traceview in Android Studio 1.2 Beta 3?

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms, android-traceview

Android Studio was nicely integrated with Traceview (http://tools.android.com/tips/traceview). But I've recently updated to 1.2 Beta 3 and can't find this button. Can you help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found it under the 'CPU' tab in the 'Android' view:

[image]

The 'CPU' view [was added](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12preview2available) in the AS 1.2 Preview 2 along with the 'Memory' view.

Comment: it is disabled here. do you know why this happens?